# apply css transition to IDs?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

im trying to make a smooth transition between a display:none; property and then the same property but displayed i guess i almost want it to fade? without the use of JS.

i have written this which hides all of the titles when not hovered over the image:

```
#title-0
{
display:none;
-o-transition:all 0.5s linear;
-ms-transition:all 0.5s linear;
-moz-transition:all 0.5s linear;
-webkit-transition:all 0.5s linear;
transition:all 0.5s linear;
}
```

and i have written this which shows the titles when hovered:

```
#portfolio-0:hover > #title-0 {display:block;}
```

but the effect when hovering is just static and instant

i appreciate all the help, thank you!

Comment: You can't transition the display property, try transitioning from opacity: 0; to opacity: 1

Comment: `display` property isn't transitional

Answer (score 1):

You can't transition the display property, if I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, it can be done with opacity:

```
#title-0
{
opacity: 0;
-o-transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
-ms-transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
-moz-transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
-webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
}

#portfolio-0:hover > #title-0 {display:block;}
```

Comment: `opacity` reserves space

Comment: Yes it does. If this is a problem you'll have to either position the element or transition the height as well

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do transition on the display property. You can set the opacity of your `#title-0` to `0` instead:

```
#title-0
{
    -o-transition:all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition:all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s linear;
    transition:all 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

then revert the opacity to `1` on hover of `#portfolio-0`:

```
#portfolio-0:hover > #title-0 {opacity: 1}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yTq9v/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example using opacity. Also added a height transition in case desired: http://jsfiddle.net/Ty2nm/1/

```
#title-0 {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transition:all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition:all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s linear;
    transition:all 0.5s linear;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#portfolio-0:hover > #title-0 {
    height: 20px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```